# Redirect file requests (pdf, doc, etc.) to new location using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect file requests made on one domain to a subdomain. There are a mixture of files being requested: .doc, .docx, .pdf, .ppt, and .pptx.

I have so far been unsucessful in trying to write the rule that would make this happen:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.org\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.org\.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^dir1\/subdir1\/subdir\/(.+\.(pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx)$ "http\:\/\/subdomain\.domain\.org\.uk\/newdir\/$1" [NC,R=302,L]
```

I have tried this with and without the HTTP_HOST conditions.

Please can someone point me in the right direction as to why this isn't working?

Thank you.

EDIT

.htaccess sample

```
#The first rule
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.org\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#The last (working) rule before the rule I'm trying to implement
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.org\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.org\.uk$
RewriteRule ^apply\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/subdomain\.domain\.org\.uk\/$1" [R=301,L]

#The rule I'm trying to get working
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.org\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^dir1/subdir1/subdir/(.+\.(pdf|docx?|pptx?))$ http://subdomain.domain.org.uk/newdir/$1 [R=302,NC,L]
```

Comment: I have been advised by the provider that "static files such as .pdf or .doc will bypass Apache as they are not served by nginX. The only way to make this work would be to enable direct push for the domain".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some syntax errors.

This should be working as expected now

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.org\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^dir1/subdir1/subdir/(.+\.(pdf|docx?|pptx?))$ http://subdomain.domain.org.uk/newdir/$1 [R=302,NC,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work either: the files continue to be loaded from their original directory. I tried with and without the backslashes before each character (e.g. "http\:\/\/subdomain\.) too (all other rules I have include them and work okay). Thanks for pointing out the missing closing parenthesis. I also notice you have changed the file extensions from, for example, doc|docx to docx? Please can you explain this? Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have other rules in your htaccess ? If so, can you update your question with entire code ? About my code, you don't need other backslashes than i used. For `docx?` this means `doc` or `docx` (same for `pptx`). Yours was fine, this is just a more elegant and shorter way of doing it

Comment: I have edited the question to include a sample of the htaccess file - the first rule and the last rule before the one in question. Cheers.

Comment: I also tried to implement as a wildcard redirect from the domain directory to the subdomain directory.

Comment: What is the URL you're trying to access ? Are your pdf,doc,etc files real physical files ?

Comment: A further update: I have been advised by the provider that "static files such as .pdf or .doc will bypass Apache as they are not served by nginX. The only way to make this work would be to enable direct push for the domain".

Comment: I can confirm that this rule worked after nginx was disabled. Thank you.